# Laravel 5: How to store extra attributes to user login session

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, google-authenticator

I'm actually implementing 2-factor auth into the project. What I did was

```
Auth::user()->google2fa_passed = 1;
```

In fact it doesn't really store, when navigate to another page, the value is missing.

I also don't want to keep in another session, because when user logout *(or users remove the session cookie from their browser)*, then will show a login page, and go through the 2 factor auth again.

Any idea how to save 1 more attribute to user session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I use `session` to store.

After key in the 6-digits code, store a flag into session

```
\Session::put('totp_passed', 1);
```

In **app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php**, remove the *2FA session* if session expired

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        // remove the 2-factor auth if the user session expired
        \Session::forget('totp_passed'); // <------- add this line

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('auth.login');
        }   
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Then create another middleware, e.g. **app/Http/Middleware/TwoFactorAuth.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TwoFactorAuth
{
    /** 
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        if (!\Session::has('totp_passed')) {
            return redirect()->route('auth.2fa');
        }   

        return $next($request);
    }   
}
```

In **app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
    'auth'       => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest'      => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    '2fa'        => \App\Http\Middleware\TwoFactorAuth::class, // <------ add this line
];
```

#### How to use

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // must be login first only can access this page
    Route::get('2fa', ['as' => 'auth.2fa', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@get2FactorAuthentication']);
    Route::post('2fa', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@post2FactorAuthentication']);

    // add 2-factor auth middleware
    Route::group(['middleware' => '2fa'], function () {
        // all routes that required login
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Auth::user()` it give you the Eloquent model of the authenticate user.

If you want to store data in session you need to use the `Session` facade or `session()` helper.

You can find more information about session [in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session).

PS: Old version of the documentation is better (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session).